# Displaying size of filtered review queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, filtering

I have filtering set in review queues to tags, I'm interested in (and understand good enough to tell, if a post is good or bad).

Yet, when I go to [review queues overview page](https://stackoverflow.com/review), the counters reflect total sizes of review queues, not count of pending reviews matching my filter.

[image]

I have to open the queues, one by one, to find a queue that has any pending review.

[image]

Can I request that the overview page displays just number of reviews matching the filter (or both counts)?

Comment: That front-page is heavily cached AND generic for all users. To make that page take the filters into account for all users would not be a minor change...and given the fact that those [filters doesn't work nice with the SQL queries...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221614/loading-next-item-from-the-close-vote-queue-takes-longer-and-longer) expect more than 6-8 ....